# Python tkinter .get method

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to make a simple app that when you place a value it either adds to the total value or subtracts from it. At this point, I made a simple format but can't get the ***.get*** method to work. This error shows up ***AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'*** on line 29. 
Thank you for your help in advance!

Here is the code:

```
#PP2_Savings_App2

import tkinter as tk



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x300')
root.title('Savings App')


#Label

deposit_label = tk.Label(root, text='Deposit').grid(column=2, row=3)

withdraw_label = tk.Label(root, text='Withdraw').grid(column=6, row=3)

#Entry

deposit_entry = tk.Entry(root).grid(column=2, row=4)

withdraw_entry = tk.Entry(root).grid(column=6, row=4)

#Class/def and buttons

def deposit():

    amount_display = tk.Text(root, width=5, height=5).grid(column=7, row=2)
    responce_text = 'You deposited ${}'.format(deposit_entry.get())
    amount_display.insert(tk.END, responce_text)

deposit_button = tk.Button(master=root, text='Deposit', command=deposit).grid(column=2, row=5)

def withdraw():
    pass

withdraw_button = tk.Button(master=root, text='Withdraw', command=withdraw).grid(column=6, row=5)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `.grid()` returns `None`, you'll need to have it on a separate line, that is, `deposit_entry=tk.Entry(root);deposit_entry.grid(column=2, row=4)`.

Comment: It almost sounds like you can't read your own error messages. If you have trouble understanding it, research each word. What is an attribute? What is an Error? What is an attribute error? What is None? What is Type? What is NoneType? What is an object? What is get? What are those in python?

Comment: @Nae, you've flagged this question as a duplicate of a duplicate.

Comment: @eugenhu Yes, there is a reason that other one is a duplicate.

Comment: @Nae Nevermind, I've read the entirety of that question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. WIll do.

Answer (score 0):

@eugenhu explained the problem but you only applied the fix once, not everywhere it was needed:

If you don't need a handle onto a widget after its creation, you can do:

```
tk.Label(root, text='Deposit').grid(column=2, row=3)
```

but if you need a handle onto it going forward, you need to do:

```
deposit_entry = tk.Entry(root)
deposit_entry.grid(column=2, row=4)
```

but you can't do:

```
amount_display = tk.Text(root, width=5, height=5).grid(column=7, row=2)
```

and expect any good to come of it as the variable will be set to the result of the `.grid()` method invocation which is always `None`.

Your code reworked:

```
import tkinter as tk

def deposit():
    amount_display = tk.Text(root, width=5, height=5)
    amount_display.grid(column=7, row=2)
    response_text = 'You deposited ${}'.format(deposit_entry.get())
    amount_display.insert(tk.END, response_text)

def withdraw():
    pass

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x300')
root.title('Savings App')

# Labels

tk.Label(root, text='Deposit').grid(column=2, row=3)
tk.Label(root, text='Withdraw').grid(column=6, row=3)

# Entries

deposit_entry = tk.Entry(root)
deposit_entry.grid(column=2, row=4)

withdraw_entry = tk.Entry(root)
withdraw_entry.grid(column=6, row=4)

# Buttons

tk.Button(master=root, text='Deposit', command=deposit).grid(column=2, row=5)
tk.Button(master=root, text='Withdraw', command=withdraw).grid(column=6, row=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now. :)